# nuget install command line "Unable To Resolve Dependency" error

Tags: dependencies, nuget, dependency-tree

I'm running the following `nuget install` command line command (indented for ease of reading)

```
nuget.exe install 
    "Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.OpenApi" 
    -Version 1.4.0 -Source [our internal feed source] 
    -Framework "net6.0"
    -OutputDirectory "packages"
    -NonInteractive
```

And it's reporting:

> Unable to resolve dependency
> 'Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.Abstractions'

The package Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.Abstractions appears to exist when I browse to in in nuget package manager, and I'm using the the version of nuget.exe (6.2.1.2 at the time of writing).

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that the dependency was a pre-release version.

Stipulating the `-prerelease` command-line flag fixed this issue.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/cli-reference/cli-ref-install